# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

my .htaccess file have the following code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

#php_flag display_errors on

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
#<files *.html>
#SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
#</files>



#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^12\.188\.175\.226
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance\.html$
#RewriteRule (.*).html$ /maintenance\.html [R=302,L]

#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^12\.188\.175\.226
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance\.html$
#RewriteRule ^$ /maintenance\.html [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)find-junkyards.com [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)findjunkyards.net [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^junkyardsnearme.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.junkyardsnearme.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.junkyardsnearme.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.junkyardsnearme.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_req=/$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


#ErrorDocument 404 http://dev.junkyardsnearme.com/admin/accounts/error404
```

this allow to redirect me if i put the correct url but it is not redirect to the index.php if the url is not correct instead it gives me an default 404 error.

if i remove the following lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_req=/$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

it will not allow me to go through the website flow. I have also tried the

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_req=/$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

but still it doesn't work for me.

any idea why this not work please answer quickly it would be great help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and what URL is giving 404? Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Thank for Suggestion but i got solution my .htaccess code redirect me to an controller.php file where the error message is written then i changed the path from there and display my own custom 404 page.

Comment: So your problem solved now?